# How to repair my login redirect in django

Tags: django, django-views

The urls in my django project started to fail.
So in my templates I had to change {% url 'home' %} for {% url 'app1:home' %}
and also my urls, so my urls works fine but not the redirect when log in or log out. 
I have

```py
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

But now I get NoReverseMatch, reverse from home don't work.

```py
# my app1.urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import HomePageView, VentasPageView, AcercaPageView
from .views import buscar

app_name = 'app1'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('ventas/', VentasPageView.as_view(), name='ventas'),
    path('buscar', buscar, name='buscar'),
    path('acerca/', AcercaPageView.as_view(), name='acerca')
]
```

What should I do?
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make exactly the same change to your URL settings:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'app1:home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'app1:home'
```

or provide actual URLs, e.g.,:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Comment: I can't really answer that without knowing what changes you made to your project. The issue cannot just have happened by itself - you must have changed your URL configuration.

Comment: (most likely you added `app_name` to your apps `urls.py`, which applies a namespace to the URLs defined there).